# MySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual

Tags: mysql

Code:

```
    function prepare_items() {
    global $wpdb;
    $per_page = 10;
    $columns = $this->get_columns();
    $hidden = array();
    $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();

    $this->_column_headers = array( $columns, $hidden, $sortable );
    $this->process_bulk_action();

    $orderby = ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['orderby'] ) ) ? sanitize_sql_orderby( $_REQUEST['orderby'] ) : 'id'; //If no sort, default to title
    $order = ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['order'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['order'] ) : 'desc'; //If no order, default to desc
    $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
    $post_table_name  = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';

    $where = "1=1";
    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['accommodation_id'] ) ) $where .= " AND Trav_Vacancies.accommodation_id = '" . esc_sql( trav_acc_org_id( $_REQUEST['accommodation_id'] ) ) . "'";
    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['room_type_id'] ) ) $where .= " AND Trav_Vacancies.room_type_id = '" . esc_sql( trav_room_org_id( $_REQUEST['room_type_id'] ) ) . "'";
    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['date'] ) ) $where .= " AND dates.date_from <= '" . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['date'] ) . "' and dates.date_to > '" . $_REQUEST['date'] . "'" ;
    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['location'] ) ) $where .= " AND Trav_Location.meta_value = " . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['location'] );
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) { $where .= " AND accommodation.post_author = '" . get_current_user_id() . "' "; }

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT Trav_Vacancies.* , accommodation.ID as acc_id, accommodation.post_title as accommodation_name, room_type.ID as room_type_id, room_type.post_title as room_type_name, dates.date_from as date_from, dates.date_to as date_to FROM %1$s as Trav_Vacancies
                    INNER JOIN %2$s as accommodation ON Trav_Vacancies.accommodation_id=accommodation.ID
                    INNER JOIN %2$s as room_type ON Trav_Vacancies.room_type_id=room_type.ID
                    INNER JOIN %8$s as Trav_Location ON (Trav_Vacancies.accommodation_id=Trav_Location.post_id AND Trav_Location.meta_key = \'trav_accommodation_country\')
                    INNER JOIN rus_trav_dates as dates ON Trav_Vacancies.date_id = dates.id
                    WHERE ' . $where . ' ORDER BY %4$s %5$s
                    LIMIT %6$s, %7$s' , TRAV_ACCOMMODATION_VACANCIES_TABLE, $post_table_name, '', $orderby, $order, ( $per_page * ( $current_page - 1 ) ), $per_page, 'rus_postmeta');

    $data = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );

    foreach($data as &$d){
        $from = explode('-', $d['date_from']);
        $d['date_from'] = $from[2].'-'.$from[1].'-'.$from[0];
        $to = explode('-', $d['date_to']);
        $d['date_to'] = $to[2].'-'.$to[1].'-'.$to[0];
    }

    $sql = sprintf( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %1$s as Trav_Vacancies INNER JOIN %2$s as accommodation ON Trav_Vacancies.accommodation_id=accommodation.ID WHERE %3$s' , TRAV_ACCOMMODATION_VACANCIES_TABLE, $post_table_name, $where );
    $total_items = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );

    $this->items = $data;
    $this->set_pagination_args( array(
        'total_items' => $total_items,                  //WE have to calculate the total number of items
        'per_page'    => $per_page,                     //WE have to determine how many items to show on a page
        'total_pages' => ceil( $total_items/$per_page )   //WE have to calculate the total number of pages
    ) );
}
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '%1$s as Trav_Vacancies INNER JOIN %2$s as accommodation ON
>   Trav_Vacancies.' at line 1

one day ago everything works fine, today occurs this error.

Whats wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: It is doubtful that your question can be answered without seeing what do you substitute placeholders with. From error message it can be seen that at least one placeholder inside your query is left unprocessed.

Comment: Can you post sql statement after all parameters are inserted?

Comment: what is it mean "%1$s"?